# cordova plugin - pass a js function to native code

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I am trying to write a Cordova plugin which will start a thread to collect info periodically.

one of the info is maintain in js layer. So I need provide a js getter function to be called by native code.

Here is the demo code:

```
in js:
var getInfo = function() {

  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

  return jsInfo;
}

// call my plugin
cordova.startCollectInfo(getInfo)
```

How can I make java code call `getInfo` and get the value of jsInfo?

Answer (score 2):

If you pass the `getInfo()` function as the success callback to the native plugin layer, you can use `setKeepCallback(true)` to stop Cordova from discarding the reference to your JS callback after the first call, then store a reference to the callback context, allowing you to invoke your JS callback multiple times in response to your native thread operation being invoked. Something like this:

myplugin.js:

```
var getInfo = function(jsInfo) {

  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

  return jsInfo;
}

var getInfoError = function(error){
    console.error("An error occurred: " + error);
}

// call my plugin
cordova.exec(getInfo,
    getInfoError,
    'MyPlugin',
    'startCollectInfo',
[]);
```

MyPlugin.java

```
public class MyPlugin extends CordovaPlugin{
    private CallbackContext getInfoCallbackContext;

    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
        if (action.equals("startCollectInfo")){
            this.getInfoCallbackContext = callbackContext;
            PluginResult r = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.NO_RESULT);
            r.setKeepCallback(true);
            callbackContext.sendPluginResult(r);
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void onSomeThreadOperationResult(String[] someResults){
        String jsInfo = convertToJson(someResults);
        PluginResult r = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, jsInfo);
        r.setKeepCallback(true);
        this.getInfoCallbackContext.sendPluginResult(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I get the value returned by getInfo in java?

Comment: Java can't execute Javascript. If you want to access the value returned by getInfo in Java, you'll need to pass it as a string to a Java plugin method by calling `cordova.exec()` from Javascript. e.g. `cordova.exec(onSuccess, onError, 'MyPlugin', 'myPluginAction',[JSON.stringify(getInfo())]);`

Comment: So it seems it is not easy to solve my problem. I need to get the value of getInfo periodically in java, and send it to server.  can I do something else to work around?

Comment: Why can't you send it to your server using Javascript via AJAX? Why do you need to use Java to make an HTTP request?

Comment: Tnx for your suggestion. But the java code is a 3-third party API, which need to get this value.

Comment: So my above comment contains your solution: use `cordova.exec()` to pass the value from Javascript to Java. If it contains more information than a simple string, you'll need to stringify the JSON structure in Javascript, then expand it back to a `JSONObject` in Java.

Comment: Hi, problem is that, the value is changing. I need provide a callback to java code. everytime, the java code want to send the value, it should invoke the callback provided by js code to get the latest value and send it to sever. The  value is not constant, so I can not pass it manually.